# Bash/Shell replace a chunk of text from line x to line y both lines included with contents of another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Lets say I in file A have this content

```
1 <div class="a"></div>
2 <div class="b"></div>
3 <div class="c"></div>
4 <div....
5 ...
6 ...
7 ...
8 ...
9 <div class="i"></div>
```

I included line numbers which are not really there

And I have two variables in my script called `start_line` and `end_line`
These contains the line where I wish to start my replacing and the line where I wish to end my replacing

I then have a file B which is also a variable called export which contains some text that is also HTML tags (EDIT: thought of this as being irrelevant - but it is not it seems)

HOW do I go about replacing all in file A from line 4 to 7 when I know these numbers as variables and want to replace them with the contents of a file which is also a variable (can either be the file location or a cat variable of same I guess)

Been messing around with sed and the range thing -n but yeah... and also some awk - but total n00b in shell and bash here

I have so far tried (variable names are not same, but sould make sense I hope

```
sed "-n${start_line},${end_line} s/${stump_text}" "$export_file"
```

EDITED: My bad I did not inform the actual text being replaced is HTML

Comment: would be better if you add the commands you tried with sed and awk also.. it will show your effort and likely get an answer

Comment: Thank you makes sense - and I have now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed -e "${start_line} r ${fileB}" -e "${start_line},${end_line} d" "$fileA"
```

Consists of two expressions:

- `-e "${start_line} r ${fileB}"` to read contents of file specified by `${fileB}` and add it after the line address specified by `${start_line}`
- `-e "${start_line},${end_line} d` to delete lines in these address ranges

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ cat foo.awk
NR==start {                     # at start, output fileB.txt
    while (getline < file) 
        print }
NR>=start && NR <= end { next } # between start and end do nothing
1                               # print
```

Run it:

```
$ fileb=fileb.txt;  start=4;  end=7    # your values into variables
$ awk -v file=$fileb  -v start=$start  -v end=$end  -f foo.awk  fileA.txt
```

Comment: Looks like this could be the way to go - but thrown off by the foo.awk - is that a file you are making that contains a sort of a awk function you then invoke in your awk function call?

Comment: `foo.awk` is the awk program file. You could just run the program like `awk -v ... 'NR==start { ... } 1' fileA.txt` but it's easier to explain it with comments when laid out like that. Just cut and paste the program to file `foo.awk` and run it like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you mean, and `$export_file` contains the name of the file, and `$stump_text` the text to replace the contents from `$start_line` to `$end_line` with, this should go:

```
sed -i '${start_line},${end_line}s/.*/${stump_text}/' "$export_file"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I tried it but got

sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Please note that if you are on Windows, using the default command prompt, you will have to double-escape a backslash `\`  -> `\\\`, otherwise you will get this error. On Linux, you will have to escape them once: `\\`. This might or might not be related to your issue.

Comment: Please disregard code formatting in the previous comment, there seems to be a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286364/339245). \ -> \\\ and \\ are what I intended to write.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, but not pretty - and could probably become prettier.

I could not import as a string due to escape problems I thing.
I could not retain the insert from fileB to fileA so needed a tmp file to hold

Here is solution

```
sed -i "${start_line},${end_line}d" "$fileA"
sed -e "${start_line}r ${fileB}" "$fileA" > "$fileA.out"
mv "$fileA.out" "$fileA"
```

If anyone can make it prettier please do - I need to learn :-)

Comment: your question title clearly states you want to delete range of lines and add contents from another file instead.. where does `could not import as a string due to escape problems` come into picture?

Comment: Well I did not post ALL of my efforts to try to get it to work, one of the attempts was to create a variable to hold it using cat - sorry for not making that clearer

Comment: the `r` command addresses that case by accepting filename directly, so that one doesn't get tripped with new lines, regex meta characters and such...